# How to load a site depending on hours and minutes

Tags: javascript

I have four screens that I want to display in the following order.

Screen1(2 seconds) -> Screen2 (2 seconds) -> Screen3 (2 Seconds)

I also have a fourth screen which should only show when the time is between 05:55-06:05 and 17:55-18:05

In order to accomplish this my code looks like this till now:

```
function timecondition() {
        var hours = new Date();
        var minutes = new Date();
        var h = hours.getHours();
        var m = minutes.getMinutes();
        var timecondition;
        if((h == 5 && m >= 55) || (h == 6 && m <= 5) || (h == 17 && m >= 55) || (h == 18 && m <= 5)) {
            timecondition = true;
        }
        else {
            timecondition = false;
        }
        return timecondition;
    }
    $(document).ready(
        function() {            

            setInterval(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if(timecondition()) {
                        $('#show').load("http://localhost:8084/test/screen4");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#show').load("http://localhost:8084/test/screen1");
                    }
                }, 2000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if(timecondition()) {
                        $('#show').load("http://localhost:8084/test/screen4");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#show').load("http://localhost:8084/test/screen2");
                    }
                }, 4000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if(timecondition()) {
                        $('#show').load("http://localhost:8084/test/screen4");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#show').load("http://localhost:8084/test/screen3");
                    }
                }, 6000);
            }, 6000);      
        }
    );
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work like I want it to be.
When I start the webapplication at 05:54 the sequence(screen1->screen2->screen3)
But once the clock hits 05:55 it won't display the fourth screen, like it was in my intention.
When I start the application within the timecondition eg. at 05:56 it shows the fourth screen, but won't leave screen4 when the timecondition is not true anymore a few minutes later.

Is it because I need dynamic functions?

Comment: I cannot tell why your screen4 is not shown, however I see your boolean condition is invalid because you do not combine hours and minutes together, so that 5:05, 17:05 and 18:55 etc. also match right now. Also creating two dates of *now* is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of potential bugs there.

## 1. You are taking the time twice

Every time you call `new Date()` you are taking a snapshot of an instant. In this case they are only milliseconds away from each other, but it's a bug nonetheless.

```
var hours = new Date();
var minutes = new Date();
```

One object should be enough:

```
var now = new Date();
var h = now.getHours();
var m = now.getMinutes()
```

## 2. Your time condition is wrong

```
var timecondition;
if((h == 5 || h == 6 || h == 17 || h == 18) && (m >= 55 || m <= 05)) {
    timecondition = true;
}
else {
   timecondition = false;
}
return timecondition;
```

There is two problems with this:

a) It is hiding the function name from within. This is just a minor bug and doesn't affect the functionality here yet.

b) You are checking for hours and minutes independently. This IS a serious bug because it doesn't comply with your business logic.

That whole code above can be smarter rewritten as:

```
h = h % 12
return (h == 5 && m >= 55) || (h == 6 && m <= 5)
```

## 3. You reload the page every few seconds

The second argument to `setInterval` and `setTimeout` respectively is in milliseconds. So you are issuing a `load` every 2 seconds.

## 4. You are nesting timeouts within intervals

This basically means that every six seconds you are setting a timer for the next 2, 4 and 6 seconds. This is not really a bug, but unnecessarily complex. Why not set one interval for running every two seconds?

Here's some refactored and hopefully fixed code. Didn't try it out yet, though.

```
function slideshow() {
    var screens = [
        "http://localhost:8084/test/screen1",
        "http://localhost:8084/test/screen2",
        "http://localhost:8084/test/screen3"
    ];
    var specialScreen = "http://localhost:8084/test/screen4";
    // Contains the index of currently shown screen or -1
    // when the special screen is shown
    var currentScreen = 0;
    // Cache the element here so we don't need to search for it every two seconds
    var show = $('#show');

    function timecondition() {
        var now = new Date();
        var h = now.getHours();
        var m = now.getMinutes();
        h = h % 12;
        return (h == 5 && m >= 55) || (h == 6 && m <= 5);
    }

    function update() {
        if (timecondition()) {
            if (currentScreen != -1) {
                show.load(specialScreen);
                currentScreen = -1;
            }
            return;
        }
        currentScreen = (currentScreen + 1) % screens.length;
        show.load(screens[currentScreen]);
    }
    setInterval(update, 2000);
}
$(document).ready(slideshow);
```

If you wanted different durations for the screens, you could do it roughly like this:

```
 function slideshow() {
    var screens = [
        {url: "http://localhost:8084/test/screen1", t: 2000},
        {url: "http://localhost:8084/test/screen2", t: 3000},
        {url: "http://localhost:8084/test/screen3", t: 10000}
    ];
    var specialScreen = "http://localhost:8084/test/screen4";
    // Contains the index of currently shown screen or -1
    // when the special screen is shown
    var currentScreen = 0;
    // Cache the element here so we don't need to search for it every two seconds
    var show = $('#show');

    function timecondition() {
        var now = new Date();
        var h = now.getHours();
        var m = now.getMinutes();
        h = h % 12;
        return (h == 5 && m >= 55) || (h == 6 && m <= 5);
    }

    var step = 1000;
    var screenTimer = 0;
    function update() {
        if (timecondition()) {
            if (currentScreen != -1) {
                show.load(specialScreen);
                currentScreen = -1;
            }
            return;
        }
        if ((screenTimer += step) >= screeens[currentScreen].t) {
            currentScreen = (currentScreen + 1) % screens.length;
            show.load(screens[currentScreen].url);
            screenTimer = 0;
        }
    }
    setInterval(update, step);
}
$(document).ready(slideshow);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Hubert! That worked great! I have one little question left. How do I go on when I want different intervals for the screens? Eg Screen1 3 seconds, screen2 10 seconds and screen3 5 seconds?

Comment: @mrk I would go for an interval of the biggest common divisor and counting inside that. In this case you would set up an interval of 1s and count down a number, e.g. from 10 down. Once it reaches 0, switch screens, reset that counter and go for the next number. You could use an array of countdowns for that.

Comment: By the way, if your screens don't change over time too much, you could also just load them once and show them one at a time while the others are hidden. This would greatly reduce server traffic and it would make your web page runnable offline after the initial loading.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get what you mean (biggest common divisor//array for countdowns) :/ Is it possible to show that in a code example?